# Stuttering audio with PyAudio on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, udp, raspberry-pi, raspbian, pyaudio

I'm trying to make a simplex communication (that will become half-duplex as soon as I solve this issue) between two Raspberry Pi.

One sends audio packets through UDP protocol and the other receives this packets and plays them through it's default audio output device.

I'm using the PyAudio library.
I managed to make the communication work, but the sound that comes out is stuttered.
The code I used is the following:

Client (IP address: 192.168.1.40)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pyaudio
import wave
import socket

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
            channels=1,
            input_device_index=2,
            rate=44100,
            input=True,
            frames_per_buffer=8192)

print("Stream on.")
while True:
try:
    data = stream.read(8192)
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.connect(("192.168.1.30", 1000))
    sock.send(data)
    sock.close()

except KeyboardInterrupt:   
    print("Stream off.")
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()
```

Server (IP address: 192.168.1.30)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pyaudio
import wave
import socket

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
            channels=1,
            input_device_index=2,
            rate=44100,
            output=True,
            frames_per_buffer=8192)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) 
s.bind(('0.0.0.0', 1000)) 

while True:
try:
    data = s.recv(8192)
    if data:
        stream.write(data)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    s.close()
    print "Exiting code."
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: i had a similar issue in the past, sending larger packets of data at once helped but increased the latency, if thats not an issue thats probably your best bet

Comment: Hello, thank you for the suggestion. I've tried to increase the packet size, but nothing has changed

Answer (score 1):

I too faced similar issues of stuttering. This was because of the input overflowed error which came up during the streaming. If the chunk size of every communication is reduced to 512bytes the communication is coming out well as per my experience.